# After submitting the search form, it redirects to a blank page

Tags: laravel, controller, routes, laravel-7, search-form

I have a multi-column search form inside the 'users.index' view. The form is as mentioned below:

```
<form method="get" action="{{route('search')}}">
   <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="name">
   <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="role">
   <select name="status">
      <option disabled selected>--</option>
      <option value="0">inactive</option>
      <option value="1">active</option>
   </select>
   <button type="submit">search</button>
</form>
```

And the route is this:

```
Route::get('/admin/users/search', 'Admin\Search\SearchUsersController@search')->name('search');
```

But whatever I write inside the search function of the controller, it returns nothing and redirects me to a blank page!
Let 's imagine the controller is something like this :

```
class SearchUsersController extends Controller
{
    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->all());
    }
}
```

I wonder why such a thing is happening. When I change the method of the form into Post and I determine  two different routes, the problem is solved but it 's a search form and logically the method should be get.

Comment: Do you have any other route on the same name like `search` ? Because your code looks fine.

Comment: No, I don 't have. The only other route that I have added to the web.php is this Route::resource('admin/users','Admin\UserController');

Comment: Place your new router of the same controller above resource route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found a solution. If you have resource routes in web.php file of your project, you should introduce **new routes** before **resource ones**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `csrf_field()` or `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="'.csrf_token().'">` in your form.